# Hide TextBox of MS Report

Tags: .net, textbox, ms-reports

I use the same MS Report for different code so sometimes some of parameters that are inside of the report and pointed to `TextBox` (i.e. [@CustomerGroup]) and they are  empty.

So I would like to hide that `TextBox` completely. I know that I can pass `string.Empty` but I need to hide entire title or in other words a `TextBox`.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found tha is working but a little bit ugly approach.

In code you have to do

```
 parameterValues.Add(" ");
```

And in MS Report Designer

[image]